# How to change Material-UI Button's tabIndex?

Tags: reactjs, button, material-ui, tabindex

I am using **Material-UI** in one of my **ReactJS** projects.
I have a few buttons: some - *primary*, the rest are *secondary*. What I want to achieve is to disable the tabIndex property on *secondary* buttons, leaving only the *primary* buttons accessible with the keyboard tab.

Turns out setting tabIndex attribute to the Button component does not work, nor setting the tabIndex via inputProps:

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  tabIndex="-1"  //does not work
  size="small"
  startIcon={SearchIcon}
  color='secondary'
  inputProps={{ tabIndex: "-1" }}  //does not work either
 > some text
</Button>
```

How do I achieve disabling the accessibility of the secondary buttons via keyboard tab?
I can't set tabindex attribute to an element via CSS, can I?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for textfield and input you must code like this

```
      <TextField label="1" inputProps={{ tabIndex: "1" }} />
```

for button your code must be like this

```
      <Button tabIndex="2">Button 2</Button>
```

Comment: Congrats on the first answer.
It kinda works but, using positive values is generally not a good practice. I just want to know how to set it to `-1`. Thats it.

Comment: you can create a component that always pass tabindex -1 to button and every where you want, use that

Comment: dose not worked for me, i am using IconButton

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this on the MUIv5 update.  For me, using braces worked:

```
<Button tabIndex={2}>Button 2</Button>
```

Comment: Yes with MUIv5 it expects a numeric value.